# Serverspec: "package should be installed" defaults to RPM. can't specify yum?

Tags: ruby, linux, rspec, devops, serverspec

I have this serverspec test:

```
  describe package("python-pip") do
    it { should be_installed.with_version("6.1.1") }
  end
```

It was failing and I noticed in the output that serverspec was checking packages installed with `rpm` default. Then I noticed in the serverspec docs that you can use `by()` to specify a package manager, so I tried this:

```
  describe package("python-pip") do
    it { should be_installed.by("yum").with_version("6.1.1") }
  end
```

However, this also failed, with this error:

`check_is_installed_by_yum is not implemented in Specinfra::Command::Redhat::Base::Package`

I checked the docs for that class [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/specinfra/2.28.0/Specinfra/Command/Redhat/Base/Package) and noticed this list, which doesn't include `yum`:

> check_is_installed_by_cpan, check_is_installed_by_gem,
>   check_is_installed_by_npm, check_is_installed_by_pear,
>   check_is_installed_by_pecl, check_is_installed_by_pip,
>   check_is_installed_by_rvm

So now I'm having to fall back to `describe command` rather than `describe package`:

```
  describe command("yum list installed | grep python27-pip") do
    its(:exit_status) { should eq 0 }
  end
```

This feels hacky since serverspec seems to have the functionality I'm looking for already. Is there something I'm missing?

*EDIT*

Matt's answer has helped me understand some things better, like how `rpm -q` and `yum list installed` work and how serverspec's `by()` was meant to be used (I thought `rpm -q` only showed packages installed by `rpm` and same with `yum list` but it appears they both list all installed packages). Knowing that, I have gotten my test to pass by changing it to this:

```
  describe package("python27-pip-6.1.1-1.21.amzn1.noarch") do
    it { should be_installed }
  end
```

`python27-pip-6.1.1-1.21.amzn1.noarch` is the name of the package as printed out when I use `rpm -qa` or `yum list installed`. However, it seems a bit cumbersome to have to know that entire name and use it here. I'm hoping there's a way to do this similar to how I was trying to do it above using the `with_version()` method.

**EDIT 2**

So now I know I can write the test this way:

```
  describe package("python27-pip") do
    it { should be_installed.with_version("6.1.1-1.21.amzn1.noarch") }
  end
```

So there were a few Linux-y things I didn't understand that I think are what led to this question needing to be asked. With that being the case, when Matt pointed out that searching the system packages with `rpm` is the same as with `yum`, it pretty much explained what I really needed to know.

So I realize this isn't a great question but am not sure if I should delete it since *maybe* it could help someone else but also because I appreciate the help I've gotten and want to reward it with points.

Comment: I think the reason that the `with_version("6.1.1")` did not work and the `with_version("6.1.1-1.21.amzn1.noarch")` did work is due to some kind of malformatted rpm tag for version/release/epoch/arch in the spec file. `rpm -q` normally is able to work with just the `6.1.1`, so something may be off with the rpm itself.

Comment: I can check it again, but it may be because I never tried the combination of `package("python27-pip")` with `with_version("6.1.1")`. I had only tried the latter when calling the package `python-pip`.

Comment: Oh I completely missed that. Yeah, that probably was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, take a look here (assuming you are using RHEL/CentOS/SL/OL since you said `yum` and not `zypper` or `dnf`):

https://github.com/mizzy/specinfra/blob/master/lib/specinfra/command/redhat/base/package.rb

It was a good idea to check the docs, but there are a bunch of other provider chains available that I happen to know about because I contribute to specinfra/serverspec. Unfortunately, none are `yum`.

Since there is essentially no difference in the version checking chain `with_version` between `rpm` and `yum`, specinfra does not have a command for the yum provider chain.

If you literally require that it be installed by `yum` and not `rpm`, and want to use a chain to the package method, then this is going to require a PR to specinfra. I am already going to be doing a PR to specinfra for an issue discovered in another stackoverflow question so I can always bang this one out too.

Finally, your block here:

```
describe package("python-pip") do
  it { should be_installed.with_version("6.1.1") }
end
```

should absolutely work as intended (checks if version 6.1.1 of `python-pip` is installed). If it is not, then either there is a problem with the test, your server configuration, or specinfra/serverspec. I recommend adding the output from that test since that is also a worthwhile avenue to explore.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Your answer has helped clarify some things. I've edited the original question with where things stand for me now and would be interested in your thoughts if you have a moment. Basically it has to do with what you said about how my test (as written) "should absolutely work." I've found out that the system has a much longer package name than `python-pip` (I just assumed that because it's what you use when installing with `yum`).